# no mapred-site.xml.template file in 3.0.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I am in the process of installing a pseudo-distributed node Hadoop cluster on my Windows laptop using Oracle virtual box 5.1 and ubuntu.  I have already downloaded version 3.0.0 from the mirror site. I trying to create the `mapred-site.xml` file by typing the command

```
sudo cp $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml.template \$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml
```

The `mapred-site.xml.templat`e file is not in the directory `/usr/share/hadoop/etc/hadoop`

Is the mapred-site.xml.template file not included in this release?

I have already searched StackOverflow with no success as well as googling this issue.

Answer (score 0):

there is no .template in Hadoop 3.0.0  their should already be a mapred-site.xml file in Hadoop 3.0.0. If the file is not there for some reason you can create the xml file that references the configuration.xsl

*xml version="1.0"
xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"

then you will fill out your configuration element.

try 2.7.5 if you want to cp that file